# How to add String with quotation in MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have to add a string with double **"Hide "My Account" Button"** in a C# MVC Model (.cs) file. When I am adding it directly as a string it throws an error. I am adding my code below, please chec it.

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hidemyaccountbutton")]
    [Display(Name = "Hide "My Account" Button")]
```

Comment: Using single quotes instead is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes using the \ character.
Example:

```
"The dog says \"Woof!\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape strings in C# using string verbatim like that:

```
[Display(Name = @"Hide ""My Account"" Button")]
```

or by escaping quote:

```
[Display(Name = "Hide \"My Account\" Button")]
```